# Get Buyer Email from Omnipay Paypal Express

Tags: omnipay

I integrated the Omnipay PayPal express.

After the `completePurchase()` I need the PayPal buyer email adress.

I can access the Transaction ID with `$data['PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONID']` and also the Payer ID through `$_GET['PayerID']`.

Any ideas how to get the buyers email?

Answer (score 1):

After `completePurchase()`, you need to fetch the checkout datas:

```
$response = $gateway->fetchCheckout($parameters)->send();
$data = $response->getData();

// you can check the full received data
print "<pre>";
var_dump($data);
```

And in this array, you've got a `$data["EMAIL"]` variable, wich stores the payer's e-mail address.

Regards!

P.s.: For more information and a TL;DR disquisition, [check this](https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-paypal/issues/71).